# How to avoid race condition if several clients select in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a task_id table which has two columns:

```
`tid`:task id,
`state`:0:unfinished,1:processing,2:finished
```

It's easy if I use only one client(Perl script): fetch one `unfinished` task id,update it to `processing`, process it, and update it to `finished` in a loop.

But I'm planning to use several clients to do the task. There is a chance that two clients fetch a record in the same time, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mysql table's engine is INNODB then it locks that particular row while updating the table record so other request will not be conflicted with previous update.

Comment: If your table engine is MyISAM you can lock and unlock the table explicitly.  Have a look at "LOCK TABLES" for this functionality. InnoDB would be a cleaner way to go, though.

Answer (score 2):

Have the update be something like:

```
update task_id set state=1 where tid=? and state=0;
```

then check if the update actually modified a record.